# How do I embed a TKinter animation in my web-application?

Tags: javascript, html, animation, tkinter

I have an existing Web-application and an animation that I built in Tkinter/Python that should go along with it. The animation takes user controls inputted through **stdin** and then responds accordingly. How can I embed that Python Tkinter animation in my html css javascript web-application and control it with html button inputs?

Comment: It's impossible. Especially interactivelly. Either ercord a screen or rewrite in js, obviously with jquery.

Comment: Why is it impossible? Is there something preventing someone from making a tool to do this for themselves? Or is it just that there isn't a tool that exists so far.

Comment: There is no. And probably won't.

Comment: There are some [almost failed] attempts to try and make PYTHON run in browser, letalone tkinter

Comment: Those are different languages that work on different principles, and tkinter is a librery SPECIFICALLY for working with x-server or its later replacements

Comment: It's not literally impossible, just practically impossible - people have embedded tkinter apps in web pages, though only after having spent many hundreds or thousands of hours to make it work. The fact is, tkinter wasn't designed to work in a web browser, It was designed to work with a physcial display.